# Include text files in a package

Tags: python, package

I want to include a script in a package for creating several Python source files. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

create_file.py:

```
with open("new_file.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("""import something
do_something()
more.boilerplate(here)""")
```

but this means I don't have syntax highlighting for the code (as it is a string), which makes editing it difficult.

I want to be able to do something like this:

create_file.py:

```
with open("new_file", "w") as f:
    f.write(open(path_to_source_file).read())
```

but I don't know what `path_to_source_file` should be.

Currently, the package is structured like this:

```
PackageName/
    packagename/
        __init__.py
        a_file.py
    bin/
        create_file.py
    setup.py
```

I'd imagine that I could add the source files to the `bin` directory, but then they'd become scripts, which I don't want.

Comment: By *"package"* do you mean a [setuptools distribution](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html)? If not, that's the first thing you should do, otherwise there's not really a clean way of determining your package's asset's location.

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes, I forgot to include `setup.py` in my description of the package's structure (and omitted `MANIFEST` etc. for brevity).

Comment: Ok, then take a look at [Including Data Files](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) and [Accessing Data Files at Runtime](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#accessing-data-files-at-runtime). Since your data files are actually Python source code, you shouldn't need to include them in your `MANIFEST` explicitely I think. You should just be able to use the [Resource Manager API](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources) to access your data files during runtime.

Comment: BTW, it's not the fact that some of your scripts are in the `bin/` directory that makes them accessible as command line scripts, but the [setuptools `scripts` or `console_scripts` entry points](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There are many good reasons to have code as data but even more extremely poor reasons. This smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes, I included them in `setup`.

Comment: @tripleee To set up a project that uses the library. If you've used Django, it's something along the lines of `django-admin.py startproject`.

Comment: Having the code as code -- with test cases and syntax highlighting -- is probably still a good idea. You can copy a code snippet just as well as a data file.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve!